# Unexpected result of "f\t\b\bg\n" under Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-c++, printf

I wrote a one line program in Visual C++ 6.0 under Windows XP, but the output made me confused. Can somebody explain it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("f\t\b\bg\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

> fPress any key to continue.

Comment: What were you expecting to be the output?

Comment: @Als: There should be a `g` in there somewhere.

Comment: Are you running this in `cmd.exe` or something else? If something else, can you try it from `cmd.exe` directly?

Comment: Why are you using Visual C++ 6.0?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The VC++6 runtime library is used by most Windows components, I believe, so `printf` ought to work normally.  Language support in the compiler is pretty terrible, but there's nothing in this program where that matters.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I didn't say there were. It's still ridiculous to use VC++6 in 2012, and it's going to cause the OP a _lot_ of pain further down the line.

Comment: a friend of mine made a test under VC++2008 and got the same result :(

Comment: the result is all of the same, when  running in cmd.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've played around a bit with different strings, and as far as I can tell, the Windows console follows these rules:

- After a regular character, a `\b` moves the cursor one position to the left. (This is exactly as you'd expect.)
- After a `\t` that moved the cursor *n* positions to the right, a `\b` moves the cursor *n* positions to the left. (I'm not sure this is what I would have expected, but it makes sense.)
- After a `\b` that moved the cursor *n* positions to the left, a second `\b` will move the cursor *n* positions to the left. (This is clearly not an intended behavior. I hesitate to use the term "bug", because I don't know if they ever had any intention of supporting the case of two consecutive `\b`s, but it's obviously not a "feature".)
- I don't fully understand the interaction with newlines. Suffice it to say that in some cases a `\b` is capable of moving to the previous line, while in most cases it is not; and that a `\n` earlier within the same `printf` statement can greatly affect the interaction of `\b` with `\t`, even "at a distance" (so to speak).

So in your example, `f\t\b\bg\n`, the `f` prints an `f` and moves the cursor one position to the right; the `\t` prints seven blank spaces and moves the cursor seven positions to the right (to the next tab stop); the first `\b` prints nothing and moves the cursor seven positions to the left (undoing the `\t`); the second `\b` prints nothing and moves the cursor another seven positions to the left (putting it, I kid you not, *on the previous line*); the `g` prints a `g` (on the previous line) and presumably moves the cursor one position to the right; and the `\n` moves the cursor back down to the original line.

Now, there are two small differences between what you observed and what I observed. One is that I observed a `g` on the end of the previous line (to see it, scroll rightward):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra tmp.c -o tmp.exe && ./tmp.exe
tmp.c: In function 'main':
tmp.c:3:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
tmp.c:3:26: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]                                                g
f
```

which you apparently did not; this, I attribute to the fact that I ran this from the console, whereas you ran it through Visual Studio, so you simply didn't *have* a previous line for the `g` to be printed on. The other is that you observed a `Press any key to continue.` immediately *after* the `f` (which is Visual Studio's way of saying the console app has ended), whereas I observed that if I added anything more to the end of the string, e.g., if my string was `f\t\b\bg\nh\n`, then that something-more *overwrote* the `f`. (Similarly if I tacked on an `; echo h` to the end of the Bash command.) That is, whereas in my testing, the `\n` moved the cursor to the beginning of the original line, in your testing Visual Studio somehow knew to print the `Press any key to continue.` *after* the `f` on the line. But I'm not too hung up on this; I don't really know how Visual Studio decides where to print the `Press any key to continue.`, and it's quite possible that it uses something more sophisticated (or more "sophisticated") than the mere position of the cursor.

---

For completeness, here are some examples of strings that, in my opinion, demonstrate the above conclusions:

```
printf                  console output
----------------------------------------------
"A\bB\n"                B
"A\b\bB\n"              B            [see note 1]
"AB\bC\n"               AC
"AB\b\bC\n"             CB
"AB\b\b\bC\n"           CB           [see note 1]
"A\t\bB\n"              AB
"A\t\t\b\bB\n"          B            [see note 2]
"A\tBB\t\b\bC\n"        A   C   BB   [see note 3]
```

Notes:

1. The excess `\b`s, in these cases, do *not* move to the previous line.
2. The first `\t` moves seven spaces; the second `\t` moves eight; each `\b` moves eight. So the `B` ends up overwriting the `A`.
3. The second `\t` moves only six spaces, so each `\b` moves six, and the `C` ends up strangely in the middle of `A` and `BB`.

Comment: Thank you for your convincing explanation. It helped me a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible if you wrote `g\n` past before the line start (i.e., index -1?), so my  guess is you are skipping over tab and `f` and writing `g` and newline to nowhere. Perhaps tab inserts 0 spaces in this case.

Comment: Something like that seems to be indeed the case. Under VS2010 `printf("XXXf\t\b\bg\n");` gives me "gXXf".